# UIPresentationController - presentation view size?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm using a UIPresentationController, but I can't sort out how to get it showing the way I want it to.

I'm editing the `frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView()` function, and I need to be returning the frame (a CGRect) to display my content in.

The tutorial I followed uses `CGRectInsert(self.containerView.bounds, 50, 50)`, which makes the window centered with the borders brought in 50px. If I return `self.containerView.bounds` just as itself, the view takes up the whole screen.

I'd like the overlaying view to be the width of the parent view (so, `self.containerView.bounds.width`), but I want the height to be the size needed to show the content of the new view without cutting anything off.

I tried a CGRect at (0,0) with width and height from self.preferredContentSize, but it's not returning sizes that work.. What can I do?

I tried `frame = CGRect(x:0, y: self.containerView.bounds.height/2, width: self.containerView.bounds.width, height: self.containerView.bounds.height/2)` just as a test (but that's just making the view half the size of the parent view), but when I rotate the screen, suddenly the new view is almost off screen..

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: I don't believe I ever did - I think I just found an entirely different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from `frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView()`, I also had to add the following to make it work.

```
- (void)containerViewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    self.presentedView.frame = [self frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView];
}
```